# Some Android devices report that the table (of a SQLite database) does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written an Android application that uses SQLite database which is saved in assets folder. 
This database has 4 tables: "table1", "table2" and "table3" and "android_metadata" . The application works fine on most devices, but some crashes have been reported.  So I used acra (Application Crash Report for Android, http://code.google.com/p/acra/ ) to collect the log.
I am sure that the database has "table2" table, however the log says there is no such table. I really wonder why it works fine on some devices, but crashes on some others ?
The model of phone is Samsung GT-I9001GT, Android 2.3.3 . Some HTC desire HD had this problem too.
Please help me resolve it. Thanks.

### (The database file size is 33KB)

Log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{english.idiom/english.idiom.Category2Activity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table2: , while compiling: SELECT subject,table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id=8
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table2: , while compiling: SELECT subject,table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id=8
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.getContents(Category2Activity.java:176)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.Initialize(Category2Activity.java:138)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.onCreate(Category2Activity.java:70)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table2: , while compiling: SELECT subject,table2_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id=8
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.getContents(Category2Activity.java:176)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.Initialize(Category2Activity.java:138)
    at english.idiom.Category2Activity.onCreate(Category2Activity.java:70)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have to check the devices you're willing to support. See

```
/data/
```

and check if you have the corresponding table. I've been there, and some devices really differ in terms of package naming, etc.

You can use an app something like, [aSQLiteManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager&feature=search_result) to browse schemas.

Other useful sources:

[Debugging sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device)

[Android: Where are database files stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105219/android-where-are-database-files-stored)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I used String DB_PATH = "/data/data/english.idiom/databases/ . Does this File dbFile = getDatabasePath(MY_DB_NAME); work?

Answer (score 0):

My question is: do you have other SQL errors in ACRA logs? Particularly, about database corruption?

In my question: [Better SQLite corruption detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973527/) I presented the quick analysis of SQLite behavior when DB file was randomly modified. When "SELECT *" was failing, sometimes SQLite claimed that it was because the table didn't exist. When I loaded the modified DB file into editor, all tables were missing - so, random modification of the DB file may actually erase all your tables.