# Does SQLite checksum its data?

Tags: sqlite

Harddrive bit-rot [does happen](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/8794/). I'm using SQLite for a project with fairly critical data. Obviously, I'll be taking regular backups of the database, but **does SQLite checksum its data?**

I've read about the [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check), but can't really say whether it does integrity check on the actual data. The page "[How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)" doesn't really mention the fact about bit rot on a harddrive, which is the reason why I'm asking.

Also, the database I am dealing with will be an indexable append-only log. One option would be for me to rotate the database regularly and create an MD5 sum of each rotated file. But maybe that's too much work...

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the integrity_check documentation, I would say it would *not* be guaranteed to detect corruption that only affects user data (due to undetected bit errors on media).

Since your data is an append-only log, you've got it pretty easy. One way would be to write a text file log on a separate hard drive that contains hashes (MD5 or whatever) of every row of your data. Then you can use that hash log to verify the contents of the real database. Obviously backups will be an integral part of your plan.

Comment: Yes, sadly it seems that integrity_check does not do this.

Also, if I simply would like to detect corrupt rows I could probably store the MD5 hashes in the same database, since I would still be able to detect corruption. Or did you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Storing the hash in the same row as the data might be sufficient for your purposes. Perhaps I was thinking of malicious tinkering of the data - an attacker would only need to tweak the data in one place if the hash is stored in the same row as the data. Storing the hash log on a separate drive (also with separate security credentials) could protect against that too.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this; I could be using the [fzec](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zfec/) Python package to recover broken data. Each row would have multiple "fzec block columns" to recover from corruption. Seems pretty neat.